# Script to show file differences

Tags: io-redirection

I am trying to find the difference of my 2 files and can't get it to produce anything. Here is what I've done

```
#Compare files and redirect output
ACTUAL_DIFF=`diff file.current file.previous 2>/dev/null`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Comparing /tmp/file.current state (<) to /tmp/file.previous state (>), difference is: "
        echo ""
        echo $ACTUAL_DIFF | cut -f2,3 -d" "
        echo ""
    else
        echo "The current file state is identical to the previous run (on `ls -l file.previous | cut -f6,7,8 -d" "`) OR this is the initial run!"
        echo ""
    cat /tmp/file.diff
        echo ""
fi
```

Comment: TY for correcting it. When I copied and paste, it was in the same format as yours. Not sure why it got jumbled up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the variable in quotes, otherwise the newlines will be treated as word separators, and all the output will be on a single line:

```
echo "$ACTUAL_DIFF" | cut -f2,3 -d" "
```

Another way to do this would be without the variable, just pipe `diff` directly to `cut`:

```
diff file.current file.previous 2>/dev/null | cut -f2,3 -d" "
```

You can use the simpler `cmp` command at the beginning just to test if the files are different.

And to put the output in a file while showing it, use the `tee` command.

```
#Compare files and redirect output
ACTUAL_DIFF=`diff file.current file.previous 2>/dev/null`
if ! cmp -s file.current file.previous 2>/dev/null
then
    echo "Comparing /tmp/file.current state (<) to /tmp/file.previous state (>), difference is: "
    echo ""
    diff file.current file.previous 2>/dev/null | cut -f2,3 -d" " | tee /tmp/file.diff
    echo ""
else
    echo "The current file state is identical to the previous run (on `ls -l file.previous | cut -f6,7,8 -d" "`) OR this is the initial run!"
    echo ""
    cat /tmp/file.diff
    echo ""
fi
```

Comment: TY for the help, but still not putting output in a file.

Comment: Putting output in what file? There's nothing that writes to a file in the script.

Comment: Are you talking about `/tmp/file.diff`? Nothing creates that file, and it's only printed in the `else` block, which is run when the file hasn't changed.

Comment: That is my issue..... I need to put the output into a file and not sure how. I want to name the output file /tmp/file.diff.

Comment: Why doesn't the question say anything about that?

Comment: I've added the `tee` command to put the output in a file at the same time as it's displayed on the terminal.

Comment: TY for your help!!!! It worked!!!!

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solved the problem. Click on the check mark next to the answer.